# When it is a statement about a habit, a regular event, or things like that, what tense do we use in a noun clause: simple past or present perfect?

Tags: tense

When it is a statement about a habit, a regular event, or things like that, what tense do we use in a noun clause: simple past or present perfect?

1

> Whenever I go out, I have to check multiple times whether I **have locked** the door or not.

2

> Whenever I go out, I have to check multiple times whether I **locked** the door or not.

In my view:

Using simple past here is weird because it sounds like a specific event that happened in the past.

Using present perfect is ok to my ears, but I don't know why.

Can you tell me why?

Comment: As a British English speaker, I would always use your first version.

Comment: @KateBunting Do you have a reason or mindset for your choice? Like, why do you not use the second version (past tense)? Is it because the past tense version sounds like a specific event to you? Sorry for asking so many questions. I also prefer the first version, but I don't know why because I didn't grow up in an English-speaking environment.

Comment: I would use the present perfect for a recent action which affects the present situation. I hesitate to be too prescriptive about this because I know it isn't necessarily the same for Americans; they may say "Did you have lunch?" when I would say "Have you had lunch?" (speaking in the early afternoon). So, yes - "I locked the door" sounds to me like a single action in the past.

Comment: I would say that using version 2, I am conceptualising "whenever I go out" to mean "every individual time I go out", so that sentence 2 is an elided version of "Every time I go out, I have to check multiple times whether I locked the door when I exited". This is why it feels acceptable to use the simple past: because I am thinking of a single instance which is a model for the repetition. Whereas if I use version 1, I'm conceiving of the whole process in an abstract, general way, which would preclude using the simple past.

Comment: There is a difference here and it's regional.  I'm from the UK.  For BrEng speakers (probably all British dialects even), there is definitely a preference for using the present perfect in your first example.  The second example sounds distinctly like colloquial AmEng to my British ears. It's not wrong or anything, just different.  I am not saying that no Brits would ever utter these words, but yes they probably wouldn't. Vive la différence, I suppose!

Comment: @KateBunting I really get a bit tired with this apparent US English usage. There are tons more Americans than Brits so it might seem that way but people like me use the present perfect as you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would say “ Whenever I go out, I have to check multiple times whether I locked the door or not.” or “Whenever I go out, I have to check multiple times if I locked the door or not.”

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are (1) and (2) both acceptable? I was told that Americans and British people have different opinions.

Comment: @vincentlin no problem! i’m american and honestly either way is fine. sentence 2 just sounds more natural and fluid to me, but both are all good :)

Comment: I'm British and 2) sounds odd verging on wrong to me, so whoever said that there was a difference was right.